# Full screen changes normal design

Tags: android

I tried to run my activity in full screen mode using this method:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

But after it my all design were changed. My `Edittext`-s which had only a line below now become rectangles and buttons design are changed too.
How to avoid this situation?

Comment: what was the theme that you have used before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this theme instead:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

The theme you are applying to your Activity is old and I think even deprecated. The Holo themes are the ones you are looking for.

Comment: it says I can accept after 7 minutes.
don't worry I will do it ;)